# How to run XDoclet strutsconfigxml task in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts, xdoclet

I have a Dynamic Web Project that uses struts 1 with xdoclet.  The jars, including xdoclet-apache-modules-1.2.3.jar, are located in the XDoclet home configured in eclipse.

If I right click on the Project -> Properties -> XDoclet -> webdoclet, there is no task listed for strutsconfigxml.  What do I need to do to get that feature to show up?